# how to download brew resource manually and install?

Tags: homebrew, patch

My internet has interference so brew installation procedure may failure sometimes.

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/f80a6066e45c3d53a61715abfe71abc3b2e162a1.patch?full_index=1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4622a18a72c30c4fc72c166bee7de42903e1d036.patch?full_index=1

curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443 
Error: Failed to download resource "openjdk--patch"
Download failed: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4622a18a72c30c4fc72c166bee7de42903e1d036.patch?full_index=1
```

I manage to got that file, but I don't known the correct filename for brew.
brew --cache openjdk--patch

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "openjdk--patch".
```

brew --cache -s openjdk

```
~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/336948b1d9a8eba79fadf26569f4af0cb2fe147fde214fc9d9bf6b66f2f927d2--jdk15u-jdk-15.0.1-ga.tar.bz2
```

So how to got the correct filename for this patch?

Answer (score 0):

I found the tricky, just run

```
brew install package-name -d
```

it will print each cache name of resources used by package-name